# Looking for a way to get a word after another word, Python

Tags: python, string

How do you create a function to get the word after "class" only if it is not a quoted (by single or double, or any triple quotations) and if its spelled correctly (cannot get class d() )

```
"class hi()"  > hi

"class hi(dff)"  > hi

"class hi   (  dff  )  :"  > hi 

"  class        hi       (  dff  )  :"  > hi 

"class hi"  > hi

"classf hi"  > Nothing

"fclass hi"  > Nothing

"'class hi(dd)'"  > Nothing

'"class hi(dd)"'  > Nothing

"'''class hi(dd)'''"  > Nothing

'"""class hi(dd)"""'  > Nothing

'"""\n\n\n\nclass hi(dd)\n\n\n\n"""'  > Nothing    

"'class' hi()"  > Nothing
```

It is too hard to create using loops. If anyone can help that would be nice, thanks. This is pretty challenging,

Comment: try this: `re.search(r'\bclass\s+(\w+)',line)`

Comment: what is the source for the strings? If it is a Python source code then you could use `ast` module to extract all class names (if `tokenize` module doesn't work for you) e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585529/find-all-strings-in-python-code-files

Comment: Hmm some of the test cases dont work with that one, carrot

Comment: The source of the strings, is just a normal string, not a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

def remove(reg, s, multiline=False):
    flags = [re.M, re.M | re.DOTALL][multiline]
    s,num = re.subn(reg, "", s, flags=flags)
    return s

def classname(s):
    s = remove("\"\"\".*?\"\"\"", s, multiline=True)
    s = remove("\'\'\'.*?\'\'\'", s, multiline=True)
    s = remove("\".*?\"", s)
    s = remove("\'.*?\'", s)

    res = re.search("(^|\s)class\s+(\w+)", s, flags=re.M)
    # print "*** {} -> {}".format(s, res.groups() if res else None)
    if res is None:
        return None
    else:
        return res.group(2)
```

I wanted to use \b instead of (^|\s) but it didn't seem to want to work?

I also put together the following test code:

```
tests = [
    ("class hi()", "hi"),
    ("class hi(dff)", "hi"),
    ("class hi   (  dff  )  :", "hi"),
    ("  class        hi       (  dff  )  :", "hi"),
    ("class hi", "hi"),
    ("classf hi", None),
    ("fclass hi", None),
    ("'class hi(dd)'", None),
    ('"class hi(dd)"', None),
    ("'''class hi(dd)'''", None),
    ('"""class hi(dd)"""', None),
    ('"""\n\n\n\nclass hi(dd)\n\n\n\n"""', None),   
    ("'class' hi()", None),
    ("a = ''; class hi(object): pass", "hi")
]

def run_tests(fn, tests=tests):
    for inp,outp in tests:
        res = fn(inp)
        if res == outp:
            print("passed")
        else:
            print("FAILED on {} (gave '{}', should be '{}')".format(inp, repr(res), repr(outp)))
```

Comment: '"""class hi(dd)"""'   doesnt seem to work, thanks for replying

Answer (score 4):

Something like this, maybe?

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from tokenize import generate_tokens
from token import NAME

def classname(s):
    g = generate_tokens(StringIO(s).readline)   # tokenize the string
    it = iter(g)
    for toknum, tokval, _, _, _  in it:
        if (toknum == NAME and tokval == 'class'):
            return it.next()[1]

print classname("class hi(29):")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\s*class\s+(\w+)")
```

For example:

```
>>> line_to_test = "  class        hi       (  dff  )  :" 
>>> match = pattern.match(line_to_test)
>>> match
<org.python.modules.sre.MatchObject object at 0x3>
>>> match.groups()
('hi',)
```

Comment: you need to remove quoted strings => then regular expression will not be so easy.

Comment: @ddzialak: I don't get your meaning. OP doesn't want to match quoted strings.

Comment: This is working good for most of the test cases, but for "classf hi"  your method gives "f",  it should give nothing

Comment: @user1357159: Fixed. I changed the second `*` to a `+` above. Should work fine now.

Comment: I've tested both this and ffao's answer with the time module and this one seems to go faster.

Comment: @user1357159: try it on "a = ''; class D(object): pass". ffao's is a better solution than regular expressions. Joel Cornett's solution takes advantage of a missing test case in your given test data (a case *following* a string).

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all substrings that are enclosed in quotes (i.e., `'`, `"` and `'''` or `"""`).
2. Use regular expressions to match the expression "class (name of class here)".

You may need to tweak the regular expression to properly match all valid Python identifiers for class names:

```
import re
m = re.match("class ([\w]+)", "class hi")
print m.group(0)
```